# expo-apple-authentication no email address

Tags: react-native, expo, single-sign-on, apple-sign-in, apple-sso

I am implementing SSO into a mobile app. I have Google SSO set up and working, and just need to finish up with Apple now.

I just need to figure out one last thing and I am good to go. The first time I tried signing in with Apple, I get a response in the structure:

```
{
  authorizationCode: '...',
  email: null,
  fullName: {
    familyName: null,
    givenName: null,
    middleName: null,
    namePrefix: null,
    nameSuffix: null,
    nickname: null,
  },
  identityToken: '...',
  realUserStatus: 1,
  state: null,
  user: '...',
}
```

My issue is now when I try to sign in with Apple, I am not getting the `email` in the response from Apple. Does anyone know how to fix or overcome this?

My `signInWithApple` function is as follows:

```js
import * as AppleAuthentication from 'expo-apple-authentication'

const signInWithApple = async () => {
  try {
    const userInfo = await AppleAuthentication.signInAsync({
      requestedScopes: [AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.EMAIL],
    })
    return userInfo
  } catch (error) {
    throw error.code
  }
}

export default signInWithApple
```

**EDIT**

I have seen someone online mention decoding the `identityToken`, and this did give me the email address, just want to confirm now whether or not this is the right thing to do?